# How does the decorator @staticmethod in Python get rid of the instance object?

Tags: python, oop, decorator, static-methods, python-decorators

As far as I have understood, a decorator is a function that takes another function as a parameter, performs some operation on it and then returns it.

Talking about the decorator @staticmethod, what exactly does that decorator do to eliminate the instance object that is being passed by default ?

Comment: See the Python implementation somewhere at the bottom: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `staticmethod` decorator returns a `staticmethod` *object*. This object implements the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), same as functions do.

What this does is not that it gets rid of the instance, instead the `staticmethod.__get__` *ignores* binding altogether and just returns the unaltered function object. For regular functions, `function.__get__` would instead bind by returning a method object (which then tracks the instance and the function to combine them when called).

You can reproduce this by manually invoking the descriptor protocol:

```
>>> class Demo:
...     def regular(self):
...         pass
...     @staticmethod
...     def static():
...         pass
...
>>> Demo.__dict__['regular']  # bypass __getattribute__
<function Demo.regular at 0x108515268>
>>> Demo.__dict__['static']   # bypass __getattribute__
<staticmethod object at 0x1084d4f60>
>>> Demo.__dict__['regular'].__get__(Demo())  # descriptor protocol, pass in an instance
<bound method Demo.regular of <__main__.Demo object at 0x1084e2668>>
>>> Demo.__dict__['static'].__get__(Demo())  # descriptor protocol, pass in an instance
<function Demo.static at 0x1085152f0>
```

By accessing the attributes of the `Demo` class through `Demo.__dict__`, we bypass the descriptor protocol normally enforced by the `__getattribute__` method. As you can see, for a regular method a *function* object is returned, but for `static` a `staticmethod` object is found instead.

Calling `.__get__(Demo())` on either to invoke the descriptor protocol then produces a method object, and the un-altered function object, respectively. This is exactly what direct access to the same names on an instance produces:

```
>>> Demo().regular
<bound method Demo.regular of <__main__.Demo object at 0x1084dde10>>
>>> Demo().static
<function Demo.static at 0x1085152f0>
```

Note that the same protocol is also the reason that `classmethod` objects are passed `type(instance)` instead of the instance as a first argument, and also why `property` objects call the underlying function on access.